# Git Merge without checkout on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, git-merge

We have a fairly complex code base which is stretched across more than one branch (yes i know it is a bad Praxis to have more than one develop branch but we had no choice, the project is over 10 year old and rework is a nightmare)
The different branches are being synced by Jenkins script which syncs via trickle down principle all changes.

The problem is that the script is really slow due to giant code changes in the branches. Is there a way to do a checkout without having to physically checkout the repo? we need it only to merge branches.

The code is following:

```
if [ ! -d repoFolder ]; then
    git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxxx/repoFolder.git
fi
cd repoFolder;
git reset --hard;
git clean -fxd;
git checkout master;
git pull;
git checkout develop; 
git pull;
git checkout devHot; 
git pull;
git merge master;
git merge develop; 
git push;
git checkout test;
git pull;
git merge devHot;
git push; 
git checkout release/2017_design;
git pull; 
git merge test;
git push;
git checkout feature/2017-hot;
git pull;
git merge release/2017_design; 
git push;
```

Any Suggestions to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

did you try the `--depth n`[(doc)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt) option of the `clone/fetch/pull` commands?

It should be able to download only files in the last *n* commit from a branch (look at `--branch`[(doc)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone--bltnamegt)  or `--no-single-branch` options) skipping the rest of the repository

It is called *shallow copy*

Comment: Yes not an option we have more than one project which would be whiped with that option. i need to merge branches without physically checking them out.